# What to do with an outdated question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, outdated-information

This meta-question is about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826327/python3-pygame-for-debian-jessie) I asked about four years ago. At that time, [Pygame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame) for Python 3 was still in development, and was not fully released, so it was tricky to install it. My point is that, at the time the question was asked, it was legitimate.

This is, however, no longer the case, because Pygame was fully ported to Python 3, Python 2 was deprecated, and it's now completely straightforward to install that package. Indeed, both answers simply explain how to install a python package.

This means that the question is completely outdated, and that there are no ways to improve it. There are already questions about how to install Python packages, or how to backport packages in [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian), meaning there is no useful content in there. That being said, I would simply delete it.

However, due to low votes, this is one of the questions that is preventing me from asking other questions, and deleting that question would not help me to regain that right. But, as shown, there is no way to improve it either.

What should I do about it?

Just to be clear, although I already stated this fact, I am talking about a question *I* asked, and *I* also wrote the answer, so I can delete it.

Comment: Did you consider to do nothing?

Comment: The question you link to absolutely is NOT contributing to your question ban.  If you have deleted questions, those would be contributing to your question ban, especially if they are downvoted. A positively received question with an answer is contributing to you NOT being question banned.  If you were to delete that positively received question you would actually contribute to being further away from being at the threshold to submit new questions. Besides your question is ineligible to be deleted since it has a positively received answer

Comment: @rene after reading all the comments, especially the one of Security Hound, it seems to me that doing nothing is the right thing to do. If you write that as an answer, and group up the few arguments found in the comments in one place, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Even if it does not contribute to a ban, you might still want to brush up the question. If I hadn't hit this question via the meta-effect, I would instantly CV as lacking debugging details. Once the link ages away, all we know is that one did "this" to get the issue – that's frankly useless. It's impossible to answer "Did I forgot something? Is there something wrong?"

Comment: @MisterMiyagi well, there was no debugging at all because the question was more about "how to install something, I don't know if there is a way" rather than "I know a way, but I can't make it work". My whole point is, at the time of the writing, there was "no" way (ie. you could download the WIP source code and compile, but it was not packaged nor ready), whilst now there is a straightforward one. The current answer is not a way to solve the original problem, as it simply solved itself (the library was eventually packaged), it's how future readers should do, now that the package is ready.

Comment: @BlackBeans The question body is currently structured as "I did this", "I got this error", "What did I do wrong?". That *is* a debugging question, even if you did not intend it to be. Whether you update it to make it a proper debugging question or a general question – strongly consider to update it.

Comment: I'll say this after the fact: at least you did find a case where it is agreeable to say it is outdated rather than just old :) But those will be the exception to the rule in my experience, usually the content is merely old and the "outdated" part is a personal opinion. In any case, as people have said this question is actually in your benefit in its current state as it is upvoted and answered; I'd leave it alone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two aspects in your question that you lumped together.

- What to do with an outdated question
- Is deleting questions beneficial when quality banned.

Let's answer these two questions separately first and then do a nice tl;dr;

#### What to do with an outdated question

We are building a canonical knowledgebase with questions and its answers for future visitors. It is hard to predict the future so it is not up to you to decide a question is outdated. Many believe Cobol and mainframes are outdated yet a remarkable large part of our modern world still relies on those dinosaurs and let's pray that it is maintained for a few more years.

If there is nothing wrong and/or unclear about a question and deemed useful by some then a question can or even should stay. It is ready to offer value for a future visitor that is stuck in the past for whatever reason. You could edit such questions to make sure they are properly tagged.

#### Is deleting questions beneficial when quality banned.

No. The [guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584) is clear about that:

> **Do not delete your posts.**

*emphasis not mine*

The number of deleted posts is weighted heavily in the algorithm. And the specific question you linked to didn't had a negative score (at least not when arrived at it). It would actually hurt your effort to overcome a quality-ban by deleting positive scoring posts.

Instead you should focus on the deleted and negative scored posts and put effort in to salvage those. Meta can help, either by researching previous q-banned cases or present a suggestion on Meta how you plan to salvage a single deleted question and then ask if you have covered all improvement options.  If you don't post a question on meta each day I expect you'll get useful feedback. Also worth mentioning: votes takes time. I still get votes on posts I created many years ago.

**tl;dr**

That specific question can't be deleted. It has positive scoring answers. Even the community can't delete vote it, unless they do some serious damage first. Only a moderator can delete it but I'm pretty sure none of them will take the honors.

Do not touch or improve positive scoring and/or answered questions. Focus on salvaging the deleted ones or prepare for the 1 question in 6 months. In the meantime, edit, vote, flag and answer on the site as that counts as positive contribution to the community.

Answer (score -10):

If it was a question I asked and I thought it was no longer of any use to anyone - and can only clog up searches for more useful questions - then personally, I would delete it.

This doesn't help you with your question-ban, but it does (very marginally) help improve the usefulness of Stack Overflow to other people.

If it were a question somebody else asked, I would suggest to just do nothing. The potential benefit of voting to delete the question is probably very small, since the question has downvotes which make it unlikely to show up in a search (and easy to skip over if it does).

Comment: It would likely make any question ban harder to get out of.

Comment: Note that the OP can't delete that question because it has upvoted answers.

Comment: @rene According to the OP, they can delete their question if they choose to. Maybe they are wrong, but if so then the question is moot anyway.

Comment: They can’t. They are trying to build a case for a moderator to delete it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It didn't read like that to me; the OP also added *"Just to be clear, although I already stated this fact, I am talking about a question I asked, and I also wrote the answer, so I can delete it."*.